# Probability of idenitical errors on a production line

Tags: probability

(This is not homework, but rather a test study question that I'm stuck on)

There are three production lines which, in total, produce 60 widgets in one shift. After a shift, it is found that 6 out of the 60 widgets have defects. It is "rare" that two lines produce the same number of defects. What is the probability that two or more production lines produced the same number of defects?

How would I begin to approach this? My first instinct is to use Bernoulli trials, but I can't seem to see how I would set it up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are expected to assume that each widget is defective with probability $0.1$ and that each line produced $20$ of the widgets, then use the binomial distribution to find the probability that a line produces $0,1,2,3,4,5,6$ widgets.  Now the chance that two lines made the same number of defects comes down to the fact that the six were distributed $(0,0,6),(1,1,4),$ or $(2,2,2)$ compared to any other distribution that sums to six.